# How to enable Web Development feature in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, visual-web-developer

I am trying to install Microsoft Azure SDK. I downloaded this version (2.9) of the SDK from [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-azure-sdk-2-7-for-net/). And I am getting the following error in the picture.

I have Visual Studio 2013 and 2015 installed on my PC. Could it be some sort of compatibility issue. I read on some forum that it won't work if I have different versions of the Azure SDK installed on Visual Studio 2013 and 2015.

But I don't have the SDK installed on any of them. And I can't seem to find any Web Development Feature in the IDE either. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

[image: Visual Studio error]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Given the situation, the issue is most probably that the relevant modules for Web Development weren't installed when Visual Studio was installed. Those modules are not selected to be installed by default.

The solution is to simply re-run the setup and select "Modify".
On the list of modules, go to "Windows and Web Development".
You should get Microsoft Web Developer Tools in the list. Just select that and install. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 14):

@alchemist is right but I had deleted the VS2015 installer long ago (right after installing). So I went to the **Control Panel > Programs And Features > Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community with Updates > (right-click) > Change**

This will bring up the visual studio installer. Click on **Modify** > Check **Microsoft Web Developer Tools** > **Update**.

*walks towards the camera in slow motion on an exploding background